# Does anyone know how I can get rid of this additional pixel at the top of my table?

Tags: css

[There is a 1px difference between the "player" columns (on the right) and the "heading" column (on the left) which ideally shouldn't be there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkFk4.png)

I've tried everything I can think of to get rid of this but have had no success.  If anyone can tell me where this pixel has come from and also how I might be able to get rid of it I would be extremely grateful.  I am also fairly new to web development in general so if by any chance you see any bad practices or messy code while nosing around any help would, again, be greatly appreciated.

website: https://yahtzee-scoresheet.netlify.app/

github repo: https://github.com/Smickbart/Yahtzee-Scoresheet

Answer (score 1):

the problem lies in base.scss:30
Open page in Chrome . hit F12 - then highlite affected area - check styles ...

try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
<style>
    table {
        border: 0px solid #000;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to `border` property coming from `_base.scss` file

```
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #000; /* This is where it is coming from */  
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[image]

Comment: agree with Imran - you were faster than me with the answer ..

Comment: Oh Dear :) God Bless you. It's us helping developers at the end of the day and in turn learning cool stuff :) I am going to vote your answer for your kindness and a perfect answer as well.

Comment: yes Imran, we were / are all beginners and struggling, let's help where we can ...

Comment: Indeed mate ! I remember 4 years ago what my struggle was. And today, God has been so kind. Practice is what matters a lot in our field :)

Comment: Thank you both very much for your answers you've helped me fix the problem now!!!